# The padding is too big after adding grid in ASP.NET Core while it is fine in VS Code

Tags: css, asp.net-core, padding

I have been designing a site with grid and flexbox in Visual Studio Code and there everything is fine (visually). [VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6367H.jpg)

Now when I have to add the backend I had to transfer my code to Asp.Net Core (v5.0) and for some reason the padding is too much around the grid [Asp.Net Core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awOgj.jpg). The CSS files are identical. Here is my code for the grid:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: url("../background.jpg");
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 0.8fr 1fr 1fr 0.1fr 0.8fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 2fr 1fr 100px;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Any ideas what to change as everything shrinks as well and there is too much space that's not being used...

EDIT:

Here is the code from the main view:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<body>
    <div class="container container-main">
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a text-white asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a text-white asp-area="" asp-page="/Tournaments">Tournaments</a></li>
                    <li><a text-white asp-area="" asp-page="/Statistics">Statistics</a></li>
                    <li><a text-white asp-area="" asp-page="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="account">
          <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Account">
          <a> <input type="submit" value="@User.Identity.Name"/>  </a>
          </form>
        <partial name="_LoginStatusPartial" />

        </div>
        <div class="content1 flex-content1">
            <div class="flex-item flex-item1"><a>Latest News</a></div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item2"><img src="Keyboard1.png" alt="keyboard">
            <a>SOME NEWS

            </a></div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item3">
             <div class="pages">
             <button>left</button>
             <button>right</button>
             <a>date</a>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
            <div class="text"><a>ABOUT THE SITE
            </a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="content3">
            Advertise
        </div>
        <div class="footer flex-footer">
            <div class="flex-item flex-item1"><a>dsaf</a></div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item2"><a>gsd</a></div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item3"><a>jdsg</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

And here is the code from the layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - DuelSys_WEB_Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share more code about the view? So that we can reproduce your problem.If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: @QingGuo I shared the code from the main view and the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the body container's max-width property to 100% in the layout page. Please refer the following steps to update your code.

1. Add `.body-container`code in your main view style

   ```
       .body-container {

                max-width: 100%;
            }
   ```
2. Add `body-container` in class attribute in your layout .

   ```
   <div class="container body-container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
   </div>
   ```